# How to git log of all branches of a remote?

Tags: git, gitk

In my local repository, I add a new remote and fetch its history:

```
$ git remote add foo_remote git@github.com:joe/foo.git
$ git fetch foo_remote
```

Now, how to view the log of all branches of only this remote? I am interested in viewing the commits (using git log) and DAG of this remote only (using gitk).

I know that I can view the log and DAG of a particular branch on this remote:

```
$ git log foo_remote/branch1
$ gitk foo_remote/branch1
```

I want something that does this:

```
$ git log foo_remote/*
$ gitk foo_remote/*
```

Comment: @jthill Not a dup. The answers to the question is about a particular branch on a particular remote. What I want is all branches of a remote.

Comment: Yah, I'd already retracted my close vote, forgot about the comment.

Comment: See [jthill's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38987179/1256452), and note that `--remotes` takes a glob style pattern and if you don't include any wildcard characters, Git adds `/*`.

Answer (score 8):

[gitk takes rev-list options](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk), so you can e.g. `gitk --remotes=origin`

Comment: So does `git log`. :-)

Comment: initially i thought this didn't work.. but the confusion turned out to be: when you filter for a specific remote, gitk will still show other remotes for commits that are *in the lineage* of the specified remote.

Comment: @jthill YOU ARE MY HERO!

This also works:
gitk --remotes=origin/cd_* 

I'M SO HAPPY TO LEARN THIS! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5):

Viewing the commits for all the branches, you can use:

```
git log --all
```

Also, the gitk accepts the `--all` option, so you can do:

```
gitk log --all
```

You can also use this:

```
git log --graph --oneline --branches
```

Or

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

for remote branches as well.

Comment: I am aware of that option. What I want is to view only the DAG of a particular remote.

Comment: `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` will show you that or you can also do this: `git log --graph --oneline --all` for remote branches.

Comment: Sorry, it does not. It shows everything, not just the remote DAG.

Comment: @AshwinNanjappa try `--remotes` instead of `--all`. `--remotes` can be followed by `=<pattern>`.

Comment: @ElpieKay, `git log --graph --oneline --remotes` works just fine. So @AshwinNanjappa, try that.